# Adding labels to data in csv format for machine learning

Tags: scikit-learn

I intend to make a model using sklearn to predict cuisines. I however have this column in my data (Column B) that brings me a ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'indian'
please help if you can.

[csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VypRk.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide some code examples on how you open the CSV file, the part of the code where the error message occurs, and the exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to cast that column to a float somewhere in your code. If you're using sklearn, it will handle converting the label column specified into a numeric label representation. If you want to specify the string label name to integer label you can do it like this:

```
label_mapper = dict(zip(set(df['Column B']), len(set(df['Column B'])))
df['Column B'] = df['Column B'].apply(lambda x: label_mapper[x])
```